# How to get integer number from one date to another in PHP

Tags: php

Hey guys so I am trying to get the date lets say Y-MM-DD from, lets say last week to now.

So:

2013-4-8 through 2013-4-15 <-- so I want to turn the distance between these two into an integer so it should be 7.

My question is how do I get that number?

David

Comment: Php has their entire manual online.. http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
...

Comment: Asked many times on SO, but here's (one way) how to do it: `$start = '2013-4-8';
$end = '2013-4-15';
$diff = strtotime($end) - strtotime($start);
echo floor($diff/86400);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a fashion way:

```
$start = '2013-4-8';
$end = '2013-4-15';
$diff = count(range(strtotime($start), strtotime($end),86400))-1;
echo $diff;
```

[Online demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/a8Piyn)

Comment: Thanks man worked perfect