# Get the difference between two dates inclusively

Tags: php

The following code gives me the correct answer

```
//$start_date = '1/1/2013'
//$end_date = '1/7/2013'
$diff_num = strtotime($end_date) - strtotime($start_date) + 1; 
$diff_days = ceil($diff_num + 86400) / 86400;
```

However, it seems to me that there has got to be a better answer than this.  I don't like having to add a day to be completely inclusive of the range. I want to include all the days in the range not the space in between.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why don't you like adding the 1? A difference is not inclusive by nature.

Comment: This is a fence post problem... it's completely appropriate to add the additional day. Mathematically that is how it is done.

Comment: This solution is good. PHP has lots of functions, butdoes not have a function for *everything*.

Comment: What about this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16027156) ?

Comment: Be careful when calculating differences between dates using seconds. There can always be leapseconds included, giving you strange results. Better use a decent calendaring library (standard in PHP).

Comment: @HamZa solves the problem but isn't it a little space inefficient?

Comment: @Orangepill ow yes it is, at that moment I though to provide another solution since it's [answered many times on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026999/how-to-get-integer-number-from-one-date-to-another-in-php/16027156#comment22862396_16026999)

Comment: @HamZa I am not sure I would use that specific idiom but I think you got to the root of my problem.  It is not a difference problem.  It is a range.  I am doing an average on dates and instead of getting a difference I should do a range then a count.  thanks

Comment: For more information see a description of the [fence post problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error)

Comment: @Orangepill thanks but I know what the fence post problem is.  Actually the fence post problem was in an article in hacker news today.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object like so :

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2013-1-1');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2013-7-1');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$interval->add(new DateInterval('P1D')); // adds one day
```

But yes, you definitly have to add one day "by hand".

Comment: +1 still adds 1 but will avoid the leap second issue that @BartFriederichs references.